# Using Flutter's Cupertino widgets, how do I trigger a horizontal page transition on top of bottom tab bars

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-cupertino

Instead of a common horizontal page transition inside of one of the tabs or a common vertical page transition on top of the tab bar, how can I push in a page transition horizontally and on top of the tab bar?

This is commonly seen in Chinese platform type apps.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Warning: it's achievable in iOS but isn't necessarily a good information architecture for an app and not recommended by Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.

See the [App Architecture's Navigation](http://archive.is/95SWY) section and the [Bars' Tab Bars](http://archive.is/cbcYm) section.

> Use a tab bar to present peer categories of content or functionality. A tab bar lets people quickly and easily switch between categories, **regardless of the current location**.

and

> In general, use a tab bar to organize information at the app level. A tab bar is a good way to **flatten your information hierarchy** and provide access to several peer information categories or modes at once.

In Flutter, the common iOS parallel navigation patterns of horizontal page transitions *inside* each tab is achieved by letting each tab have its own Navigator and navigation stack via [CupertinoTabView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabView-class.html)s.

To undo that pattern and have horizontal page transitions *above* the tabs, do not insert [CupertinoTabView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabView-class.html)s as the root child of each tab. This will remove the parallel navigation pattern commonly seen in iOS.

Then trigger a normal route push via:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute<void>(
  builder: (BuildContext context) => ...,
);
```

or something similar.

[image]

Comment: hi,sir. You mentioned do not insert Cupertinotabview as root navigator. then using what?My Home is exactly 4 CupertinoTabView switch with CupertinoTabScaffold and CupertinoTabBar.

Comment: You said to remove CupertinoTabViews as the root child of each tab, but then how do I transition to the page? I use a tabBuilder and it needs to return the child tab,  I can't even Navigator#push to it. It doesn't even show any animation on the page

Answer (score 0):

Setting **rootNavigator** to true will solve this

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => NEWROUTE(),
    ));
```